# MS Charts Bar Charts are not showing Accurate Data

Tags: c#, vb.net

I Created a Bar Chart to show Attendance Data Location-wise...The thing is when i add more than 10 Locations,Some of the X axis Labels do not show as Expected! i've Attached 2 Images showing 2 Loactions and 14 Locations Below! Thanks!

[2 Locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luutB.png)
[14 Locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUUik.png)

Comment: where's your code, please? And also make clear what your expectation was. Have you studied the documentation to understand what the standard behaviour is?

Comment: okay...i created another bar chart...now there's another problem...here's the code

Comment: please use the "edit" feature to add code into your question. Code in comments is not readable. And please define "accurate" - again, we don't know what your expectation was. Nor, from your SQL, can we actually see what raw data was fed to the chart. That would be important - just showing a SQL query when we don't know the schema or the contents of the database isn't enough. Think about what information you'd want to know if _you_ were answering this, and didn't know _anything_ about the situation, and then provide that information. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry! but i found the Solution! It was the property "Interval AutoMode" i set it to VariableCount

Comment: ok well you can delete the question if it's no longer needed